# How to get statistics of group size after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe:

```
ID   Code    Timestamp   Value
1    AAA      12345        11
1    AAB      12346        12
2    AAC      12345         1
2    AAC      12347        11
2    AAD      12348         1
3    ABC      12345         2
3    BBB      12448         1
3    BBB      12449         1
3    AAD      12450         2
3    AAE      12450         1
4    BBD      12346         1
```

ID 1 and 2 are in one group, while 3 and 4 are in another group. I want to get the mean, min, and max for the row size of each group.

For example, the mean, min and max for the group with 1 & 2 are: 2.5, 2, 3. The mean, min and max for the group with 3 & 4 are: 3, 1, 5.

What I tried to do is

```
def partition():
  if id in [1, 2]:
    return "Group A"
  else:
    return "Group B"

groupedDf = dataframe.groupby([partition, 'id'])

print(groupedDf.size())
#print it will give me

Group A   ID
          1       2
          2       3
Group B   ID
          3       5
          4       1
```

But I could not find an elegant or pandas way to find mean, min and max as described above. All I can think right now is classical iterative way like:

```
for (key, group) in groupedDf
    #do heavy lifting calculation here to get what I want.
```

Hope the question is detailed enough and someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Group'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin([1, 2]), 'A', 'B')
df2 = df.groupby(['Group','ID']).size()
df2.groupby('Group').agg(['mean', 'min', 'max'])
```

Here's what I got:

```
       mean  min  max
Group                
A       2.5    2    3
B       3.0    1    5
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['GROUP'] = df['ID'].map(lambda x: 'A' if x in ['1','2'] else 'B')
df



    ID  Code    TIMESTAMP   VALUE   GROUP
0   1   AAA      12345        11    A
1   1   AAB      12346        12    A
2   2   AAC      12345         1    A
3   2   AAC      12347        11    A
4   2   AAD      12348         1    A
5   3   ABC      12345         2    B
6   3   BBB      12448         1    B
7   3   BBB      12449         1    B
8   3   AAD      12450         2    B
9   3   AAE      12450         1    B
10  4   BBD      12346         1    B
```

```
df.groupby(['GROUP'])['VALUE'].describe()[['min', 'max', 'mean']]



       min    max       mean
GROUP           
A      1.0    12.0      7.200000
B      1.0    2.0       1.333333
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.